# light editor for simple form and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, editor, html-editor

I need a very light editor for my simple form textbox with only these options:

```
bold
italic
*list
br
```

I don't need a very rich editor with many options like markup, wysiwyg, tinymce...etc

I want the lightest editor for ruby on rails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at TinyMCE ? It's pretty easy to configure and you can just pass corresponding parameters to include those options that you require. It does not not even require any gems or js library.
Details - http://www.tinymce.com/